# Model with extra fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Suppose I have a table with whole bunch of fields and an EF entity generated for it. Suppose I want to show an edit form for this entity, BUT with an extra field that doesn't directly map to the table.

So I create a model class that inherits my entity class and my field to it. So far so good.

The issue is that now I have to copy every single field from the entity object to the model object when returning a view and the other way around when saving data. Surely there is a cleaner way to do this?

Specific example would be a user administration form and extra fields would be password and confirm password fields, which are stored in the Membership table.

Comment: Use `AutoMapper` no need for a full answer, just google it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good practice to separate between data-transfer objects used for communicating between application tiers such as UI, and raw entities connected to the storage. Yes, you'll need to copy fields back and forth, but there are tools that can help you with this task, such as [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can make the EF entity `partial` (I think they usually are by default), and then add the field in a separate file which also has a `partial class` for that class.  It's not as good practice as Ilya's answer, but it's easy.

Comment: Putting those properties in a partial class won't help. All partials will be compiled together and seen as one model, so EF will create columns for all properties.

Comment: @CodeCaster - Depends if you're doing code first or database first.  If you already have the database, you can add whatever you want and it won't create more columns.